# wordpress display posts by terms id or name

Tags: posts, taxonomy

i have a project with types: Villa,housing... this part of the code display nothing:

```
$aProjectArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'uni_project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => 45
     )
  )

i tried also :

$aProjectArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'uni_project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'name',
    'terms' => 'Villa'
     )
  )
```

but display nothing , can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code from WordPress Docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'movie',
    'actor'    => 'Bruce Campbell, Chuck Norris',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Then display it like

```
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    <!-- your code here -->
endwhile;
```